# PHP format date

Tags: php, date, format, date-format

How can I force the date format to output:

12/12/2012, 1/10/2012, 1/5/2012

instead of

12/12/2012, 01/10/2012, 01/05/2012?

My code is the following:

```
$adatefrom = date_create($_POST['datefrom']);
$adateto = date_create($_POST['adateto']);
$adatefrom = date_format($adatefrom, 'd/m/Y');
$adateto = date_format($adateto, 'd/m/Y');
```

Please do note that I have to format the date AFTER posting it.

Comment: You find the parameters [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at the PHP built in `date` function [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

You will find that your solution is as simple as this:

```
date('j/n/Y',strtotime($_POST['datefrom']));
```

The key things to note are the characters used in the first parameter.

- `j` represents the day **without** leading zeros
- `n` represents the month **without** leading zeros

There are many other options you have, just have a read through the documentation.

*Please note that a simple search of 'PHP date' on Google would have found this solution for you*

Comment: Just wanted to mention what was done in this answer.  The key is to use the 'without leading zeros' versions of the format characters in the call to date().

Comment: @WallyLawless Amended :-) You were too quick for me

Comment: @BenCarey - actually, you were too quick on the original answer I was typing, so I figured I'd sneak in somewhere ;-)

Comment: @WallyLawless haha, I hesitated when answering as I assumed someone would beat me to it... ;-)

Answer (score 2):

```
$adatefrom = date_create($_POST['datefrom']);
$adateto = date_create($_POST['adateto']);
$adatefrom = date_format($adatefrom, 'j/n/Y');
$adateto = date_format($adateto, 'j/n/Y');
```

you are welcome! ;)